# Google Kubernetes no longer scaling up from 0 nodes in a node pool

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We use GKE to process long running jobs.  There can be a variable number of these jobs at any one time. The following is our current configuration which was working fine in GKE 1.21.  After upgrading through versions to GKE 1.24 autoscaling from 0 Nodes no longer works when attempting to schedule on the Worker_Pool.

System_Pool - 1 node (autoscaling off),
Worker_Pool - 0-5 nodes (autoscaling on)

Worker_Pool has a Label: ABC:XYZ and a Taint: DEF:UVW

We use a combination of Node Selection and Tolerations when allocating jobs so that they target the Worker_Pool node pool for execution e.g.

```csharp
NodeSelector = new Dictionary<string, string>
{ ["ABC"] = "XYZ"
},
Tolerations = new List<V1Toleration>
{
    new V1Toleration
    {
        Key = "DEF",
        OperatorProperty = "Exists",
        Effect = "NoSchedule"
    }
}
```

There is always 1 node running in the System_Pool. There can be 0-5 nodes running in the Worker_Pool, 0 nodes is desired bahaviour when the system has no load.

When we allocate jobs to the Worker_Pool using the selection criteria we get an error "**Pod conditions: Reason: Unschedulable, Message: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.**"

What is happening here? We expect GKE autoscaler to provision a new node in the Worker_Pool, but it is not.

This was previously working in GKE 1.21. Why does GKE autoscaling not increase the nodes in Worker_Pool and allocate the job there?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and Re-Creating the affected node pool seems to have solved our problem for now. Im not sure what happens during the upgrade process to break it unfortunately